# Running ng test for specific module

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a fairly large Angular8 app I'm running unit test for, i would like the ng test command to run the test for only all spec.ts files within a specified/desired module and not for all spec.ts files in the entire codebase. I tried specifying the module name in the test.ts file path but it throws module not found error in terminal, but specifying a specific component name in the test.ts file runs the test for the single component but doesn't work for module. Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's worth looking at nrwl nx. It's a tool for monorepos, but it has a functionality of testing only affected by changes parts of the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a newer version of Angular, you might use the `--include` as [stated here](https://angular.io/cli/test) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/13423)

But if you're using Jasmine you can just add the letter "f" to your `describe` as so - `fdescribe()`.

Or use it on the test itself - `fit()`

That way you "focus" on just one test or test suite and run only that.

Comment: ng test --include='**/your-spec-name.spec.ts'

Answer (score 2):

1. navigate to `src/app/test.ts`.
2. edit this line  `const context = require.context('<MODULE_PATH>', true, /.spec\.ts$/);`